# How do you get 1 specific value from a prop in expo?

Tags: react-native, image, expo, react-props

I've been trying to pass up this prop from CameraButton.js file that gives the UI of an image that was taken but whenever I activate the prop in the AddPost.js, it gives me all the values but when I try to get the singular value of the image like using console.log(props.route.params.image) and gives error undefined is not an object
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKZ1a.png)
but it works perfectly when export default function console.log(props.route.params) and shows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kDPs.png)

**AddPost.JS**

```
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/core";
import React from 'react'
import {useState} from "react";
import { View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native'

export default function AddPost(props) {
    console.log(props);
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [caption, setCaption] = useState("")
    const uploadImage = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(uri)
    }
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TextInput
            placeholder="Whats on your mind Edgers navars"
            onChangeText={(caption) => setCaption(caption)}
            />
            <Button title = "Take A Photo" onPress={() =>     navigation.navigate("CameraButton")}
              />
            <Button title = "Save" onPress={() => uploadImage()}
              />
      </View>

    )
}
```

**CameraButton.Js**

```
import { Camera, CameraType } from 'expo-camera';
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/core";
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

export default function App() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back)
  const [permission, requestPermission] = Camera.useCameraPermissions();
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [camera, setCamera] = useState(null);

  const takePicture = async () => {
    if(camera){
        const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(null);
        setImage(data.uri);
    }
  }


  if (!permission) {
    // Camera permissions are still loading
    return <View />;
  }

  if (!permission.granted) {
    // Camera permissions are not granted yet
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
          We need your permission to show the camera
        </Text>
        <Button onPress={requestPermission} title="grant permission" />
      </View>
    );
      }

  function toggleCameraType() {
    setType((current) => (
      current === Camera.Constants.Type.back ? Camera.Constants.Type.front : Camera.Constants.Type.back
    ));
      }

    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    let openImagePickerAsync = async () => {
        let permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

        if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
          alert("Permission to access camera roll is required!");
          return;
        }
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1,
          });
  
      
  
          if (!result.cancelled) {
            setImage(result.uri);
          }
    
      }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera ref={ref => setCamera(ref)} style={styles.camera} type={type}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={toggleCameraType}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Flip Camera</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => takePicture()}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Take Picture</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={openImagePickerAsync}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Choose Picture</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddPost', {image})}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Save Picture</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
      {image &&<Image source={{uri: image}}style={styles.camera}/>}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    margin: 64,
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
  },                                              
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `props[0].route.params.image`.

Comment: Thanks for the response but when I input it in the console log it still gives the same object error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the uri from the route object.

```
const response = await fetch(props.route.params?.image)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ! but it doesn't seem to work it gives a new error when i call upon the console log with the variable response [Unhandled promise rejection: Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `div` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.]

Answer (score 0):

In you file CameraButton.js set the navigation for this:

```
    <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddPost', {
              image: image
            })}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Save Picture</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

Be sure that the state image contains only the uri and not and object

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the comment but it still seems to give the same error when i try to do console.log(props.route.params.image) and gives this error, TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.route.params.image'), not sure if I missed out on a detail, thanks tho !